# Php coverting recieved String from user to date

Tags: php, json

I am trying to convert a String. I receive from users to Data

```
   $jsonObject = $_GET["UserDetails"];
   $obj = json_decode($jsonObject);
   $timestamp = strtotime('$obj->BirthDay');
   $BirthDay = date('m-d-Y',$timestamp);
```

Here `$obj` is a Json Object and it contains the following data :

```
UserDetails={"Sex":"Male","Email":"joissumanth@gmail.com","Username":"SumanthJois","Password":"iluvcoding","BirthDay":"12-March-1996"}
```

Everthing is working fine but The `BirthDay` is not working as per required, lets Say it's value is `19-March-1996` and it's being updated as `00-00-00` this is same for all the values. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank You!

Comment: The column type is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change DATE format as per MYSQL Standard like:

```
$BirthDay = date('m-d-Y',$timestamp);
```

Change with:

```
$BirthDay = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);
```

Your **[DATE format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)** should be **"Y-m-d"**.

**UPDATE:**

You also need to modify your `strtotime()` function as:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($obj->BirthDay); // don't use quotes.
$BirthDay = date('m-d-Y',$timestamp);
```

Comment: Thankyou it's working but now , instead of 00-00-00 it's 1970-1-1 for every value. what wrong now?

Comment: @Jois: answer updated, dont use quotes in strtotime()

Comment: Thankyou so much. Its working. if you dont mind can you please explain how strtotime() works?

Comment: @Jois: glad to help u, this will explain better than to me about strtotime() function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php... :)

Answer (score 0):

The default `date` format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. And the format you are using id `mm-dd-yyyy`. Try -

```
$BirthDay = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);
```

Comment: Thankyou it's working but now , instead of 00-00-00 it's 1970-1-1 for every value. what wrong now?

Comment: Because of the `'`s around `$obj->BirthDay`.